# string.replace('the','') is leaving white space

Tags: python, string, mp3, id3

I have a string that is the name of an artist that I get from the MP3 ID3 tag

```
sArtist = "The Beatles"
```

What I want is to change it to

```
sArtist = "Beatles, the"
```

I have running into 2 different problems.  My first problem is that I seem to be trading 'The' for ''.

```
if sArtist.lower().find('the') == 0:
    sArtist = sArtist.lower().replace('the','')
    sArtist = sArtist + ", the"
```

My second problem is that since I have to check for both 'The' and 'the' I use sArtist.lower().  However this changes my result from " Beatles, the" to " beatles, the".  To solve that problem I just removed the .lower and added a second line of code to explicitly look for both cases.

```
if sArtist.lower().find('the') == 0:
    sArtist = sArtist.replace('the','')
    sArtist = sArtist.replace('The','')
    sArtist = sArtist + ", the"
```

So the problem I really need to solve is why am I replacing 'the' with `<SPACE>` instead of `<NULL>`.  But if somebody has a better way to do this I would be glad for the education :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
>>> def reformat(artist,beg):
...   if artist.startswith(beg):
...     artist = artist[len(beg):] + ', ' + beg.strip()
...   return artist
...
>>> reformat('The Beatles','The ')
'Beatles, The'
>>> reformat('An Officer and a Gentleman','An ')
'Officer and a Gentleman, An'
>>>
```

Comment: You found the answer... I was forgeting the space following 'The'. I changed it from 'the' to 'the ' and thats why I was getting the preceding <space>.  I didn't know about the .startswith option.  Ill use that instead.

Answer (score 8):

Using

```
sArtist.replace('The','')
```

is dangerous. What happens if the artist's name is Theodore?

Perhaps use regex instead:

```
In [11]: import re
In [13]: re.sub(r'^(?i)(a|an|the) (.*)',r'\2, \1','The Beatles')
Out[13]: 'Beatles, The'
```

Comment: Great answer. Here's a small change that will allow it to be easily extended for other ignore words: re.sub(r'^((?i)a|the|an) (.*)',r'\2, \1','The Beatles')

Comment: Regexp is definitely the way to go here. The case-insensitive flag can solve the second question, too: `re.compile(r'^The (.*)', re.I).sub(r'\1, the', 'The Beatles')`

Comment: @Jason LeBrun and @ide: Thank you both for your suggestions.